# Buying the Full-Collection, do I get any card I haven't drawn yet, or 1 copy of any card from the core set?

Tags: faeria

The title is pretty much what I'm asking:

Buying the Full-Collection, do I get any card I haven't drawn yet unlocked, or 1 copy of any card from the core set regardless I owned them before or not?

Answer (score 1):

Purchasing the Ultimate Competitor Package (full collection) will grant you a full playset of every card in the core set. The purchase unlocks everything you need to build any deck in the current game. In addition, you will be refunded 100 gold for each booster pack you've opened or purchased so far.

Source : Faeria's Full Collection description.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What you write is what I knew so far. My problem is "unlocks" is  ambiguous to me. It  could mean "You unlock every card you need, but if you have all cards you have all you need and you'll just get the gold." Or it could mean "You unlock a set of everything you need, so you unlock 1 copy of each card, independend of what you allready have."

Answer (score 0):

After trying it out my self and performing diferent tests prior, I can say:

- You get FILLED up to 3 copys of each card.

  So having 2 copys of a card, you'll get one more of that card, having 3 or more of a copy you'll get none.

  - except "legendarys" where you get up to 1 copy of each.

    So you'll get any legendary you don't own yet.
- Destroying cards to get dust out of it reduces the gold refund

  The amount of goldrefund-reduction is tied to the rarity of the card. So lucky people who got a lot of rare stuff out of it should consider calculating, if the dust getting out of it might outvalue the goldrefund. But otherwise it is likely if you would destroy all, ending with some hands full of dust but no gold at all.
- It is true, you get even refund for unopened boosters! But the also remove the unopened boosters...

So after all (and this is just a suggestion concluding from ym perceoption, I didn't do the math!) I would say the best to do is opening all boosters you get untill you plan to by the set, and hope for getting as many duplicates with a count more than 3 as it is possible, as they will overstay the purchase of the set and can be dusted after obtaining it<sup>1</sup>, as anything else will get coutnermeassured in soem kind of value what is ensured to set the player on the loosing side of the purchase. (As far I can tell from my impressions)

---

<sup>1</sup> note even destroying a card you have more than 3 copys of, reduces the gold amount, so don't do it prior!